# Most effecient negative shape to create laminar flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, flow, turbulence

I was looking at laminar flow filters to aid in my mycology work I'm doing. Most filters use an aluminum extrusion with fins. I figured the options out there are pretty expensive for what you get and figured I could just 3d print my own straightener. Question is what shape do I use? I have seen honeycomb used and would be an easy option, but it really got me thinking about what shape would be optimal for this. We all know that when streamlining a positive body that a teardrop is close to optimal, but putting teardrops in a grid would yield a weird negative shape in the pattern. Any thoughts or ideas on this would be greatly appreciated, I plan on open sourcing the final design.

Comment: Have a look for the laminar flow system used in the Burg El Arab... Also, there was some work done for fire hoses...

Comment: What is the purpose of the filter? What particles will the filter trap, (size, shape)?